# TexWorks Does Not Work

Tags: texworks

TexWorks takes FOREVER to load.  I use it to make a syllabus.  It freezes for a long time, about 30 minutes.  Is there any way to stop this from happening?  Can I download the last version?

Comment: Is it only slow when you load a file or is it also slow when you start with an empty document? For very large documents I have also experienced larger waiting times. If it is only slow when you load one specific large document consider a) using another editor (Emacs, Ultraedit) or b) splitting the file into subdocuments, e.g. on a per chapter level.

Comment: TeXworks' homepage is https://www.tug.org/texworks/. The latest version is 0.6.5, dated March 2020.